# How to get the count of visits of 12 months of the year ( visits has checkup service in it services , total visits ) In Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I had tried to get it using the below approach, but it takes a long time. Is there a work around?

```php
$clinic=$user->Clinics->first();

$userPerMonth= array();
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
    $checkups = Visit::where('clinic_id', $clinic->id)
                     ->whereMonth('created_at', date('m',strtotime('-'.$i.' month')))
                     ->whereHas('VisitCheckUps')
                     ->count();
        
     $userPerMonth[$i]=['checkups'=>$checkups];
}

dump($userPerMonth);
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following. I've included suggestions in comments

```php
// pull only required data from database, this will optimize your query and reduce latency between the database and your app
$clinic =   $user->Clinics
                 ->select('id')
                 ->first();

// reduce round trip time between the database and your app by consolidating your query into one that will pull your desired details
$usersPerMonth =    Visit::where('clinic_id', $clinic->id)
                         ->whereHas('VisitCheckUps')
                         ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"))
                         ->select(
                             DB::raw("MONTH(created_at) as month_num"),
                             DB::raw("COUNT(created_at) as checkups_per_month")
                         )
                         ->get()
                         //transforming your results in your desired data structure
                         ->keyBy('month_num')
                         ->map(function($record){
                             return [
                                 'checkups'=>$record->checkups_per_month
                             ];
                         })
                         ->toArray();
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @mostafa-mahmoud Did this work for you?